# PERL Archive::Zip format error: bad signature

Tags: perl, zip, compression

I have a zip file created by the zip command in Ubuntu and updated by the Archive Manager included in Ubuntu.

I was trying to read the members of that archive using PERL as follows:

```
use strict;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );


my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ( $zip->read( '/home/mohamad/Desktop/VM/vm.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
    }

my @files = $zip->memberNames();
print join("\n" , @files) ."\n";
```

This zip file is about 12 GB and I know that this module has the limitation of zipping no more than 4 GB, but I am trying to see if it can at least be used to access the members of a a +4GB archive.

here is the error I am getting:

```
at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip.pm line 477.  
    Archive::Zip::_readSignature('IO::File=GLOB(0xb75ae8)',  
'/home/mohamad/Desktop/VM/vm.zip') called at  
/usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 603    
    Archive::Zip::Archive::readFromFileHandle('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0xb75c20)',  
'IO::File=GLOB(0xb75ae8)', '/home/mohamad/Desktop/VM/vm.zip') called  
at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 548  
    Archive::Zip::Archive::read('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0xb75c20)',  
'/home/mohamad/Desktop/VM/vm.zip') called at test.pm line 6 read error  
at test.pm line 7.
```

my questions are:

- Is this error the result of a having a + 4GB zip file and due to the
  module limitation , or it is something else ?
- if this is due to the 4 GB limitation, what other modules can provide the same functionality ?

what I really need from Archive::Zip is the ability to rename file members inside the Archive.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Updating Archive::Zip to the latest version fixed my issue.  Please note that zip 3.0 and unzip 6.00 had no issues with this same archive.  I think my issue is the zip contains 67121 small files all in one folder.